# How can I print a triangle of numbers in one line without 'dart:io'?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
void main() {
  for(int i = 1; i < 6; i++){
  for(int j=1; j<=i; j++){
var str = j.toString();
     String result = str + '';
      print(result);

   }
   print('');
    
    }
  }
```

Or just print `j` getting me the same result.

That's all print in multiple lines.

I tried `toString()`, but nothing changed.

Comment: you can collect them in an array, then after loop done, print the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this maybe what you want?

```
void main() {
  for(int i = 1; i < 6; i++){
    String result = '';
    for(int j=1; j<=i; j++){
      result = result + j.toString();
    }
    print(result);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
```

Another way is to use a `StringBuffer` as mentioned by @pskink which is more efficient. For example like:

```
StringBuffer buffer = StringBuffer();
for(int i = 1; i < 6; i++){
  for(int j=1; j<=i; j++){
    buffer.write(j);
  }
  print(buffer);
  buffer.clear();
}
```

Or another solution is like

```
for(int i = 1; i < 6; i++){
  print(List.generate(i, (i) => i + 1).join());
}
```

or even the one-liner:

```
print(List.generate(6, (i) => List.generate(i, (i) => i + 1).join()).join('\n'));
```

Comment: also, it's worth to mention a specialized [StringBuffer](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/dart-core/StringBuffer-class.html) for efficient string concats

Comment: @pskink I have extended the answer suggesting StringBuffer and also some other alternate sollutions.

Comment: "and also some other alternate sollutions" better too much than too little :-)